# Spark Rename Dataframe Columns

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 files in HDFS - one is a csv file with no header and one is a list of column names.  I'm wondering if it's possible to assign the column names to the other data frame without actually typing them out like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608559/how-to-assign-and-use-column-headers-in-spark).

I'm looking for something like this:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", "\t").load("/user/training_data.txt")
val header = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", ",").load("/user/col_names.txt")

df.columns(header)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to read the header file using `scala.io` like this:

```
import scala.io.Source
val header = Source.fromFile("/user/col_names.txt").getLines.map(_.split(","))
val newNames = header.next
```

Then, read the CSV file using `spark-csv` as you do, specifying *no header* and converting the names like:

```
val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
         .option("header", "false").option("delimiter", "\t")
         .load("/user/training_data.txt").toDF(newNames: _*)
```

notice the `_*` type annotation.

The _* is type ascription in Scala (meaning that we can give a list as argument, and it will still work, applying the same function to each member of the-said list)

more here: [What is the purpose of type ascriptions in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087250/what-is-the-purpose-of-type-ascriptions-in-scala)